# Using Glob to find files within a directory gives files form the wrong folder

Tags: python-3.x

When using Glob to find all of the Python files with a folder outputs a Python file from the previous folder within the directory:

**Code**

```
file_path = 'F:/Python Programs/Maths/Calculators/'
    if os.listdir (file_path):
        for org_filenames in glob.glob('*.py'):
            print (new_filenames)
```

**Output**

```
SELECTOR
```

(I don't know how to format this properly, sorry if it's hard to read.)

The python file that is finding subfiles is called selector and is in 'F:/Python Programs/Maths/' but I should see two python files from 'F:/Python Programs/Maths/Calculators/'.

Comment: You probably might have just wanted to do `glob.glob('F://Python Programs//Maths//Calculators//*.py')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glob.glob('*.py')` will look for files in your current working directory - you can either pass more specific path to it, like `glob.glob('F:/Python Programs/Maths/Calculators/*.py')`
or use `pathlib.Path`, which might be more elegant

```
from pathlib import Path
file_path = Path('F:/Python Programs/Maths/Calculators/')
for file in file_path.glob('*.py'): #iterate over files with .py extension in file_path folder
    print(str(file))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on my comment,

```
import os
import glob

print(os.getcwd()) #prints the current working directory.

#If you did a 
print(glob.glob('*.py')) #would print all .py files in the cwd

#to change your working directory,
os.chdir('F://Python Programs//Maths//Calculators/')
#again
print(glob.glob('*.py'))
```